# What is the term for lowercase i as word in sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

If **i** have this sentence. **i** also have this sentence.

Then correct it to:

If **I** have this sentence. **I** also have this sentence.

If we know the error is not a typo.

What would such a correction be called?

Comment: I suppose if such a "correction" were to be made to [ee cummings](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/3641342/He-had-an-ego-with-a-capital-E.html) work, he'd have labelled it *unwarranted **hypercorrection***.

Comment: This makes no sense. An error that's not a typo? That's called an 'error'. And then what is the -correction- called? It's a 'correction' then. But since you're asking a questions you must mean something else. What do you mean?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94303/spelling-or-grammar-error/94309#94309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a proofreader would just call it correcting the capitalization of the sentence. There's no real distinction between lowercase "i" and lowercase "new york city"—in both cases, a proper noun is not capitalized, and should be.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of error would be recognized as a capitalization error.